# React Native - Rerunning the render method

Tags: react-native, dynamic, react-lifecycle

I have a file here that defines an icon for the title.

```
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        return {
            headerRight: () => (<HomeHeaderIcon/>)
        }
    };
```

HomeHeaderIcon.js

```
export default class HomeHeaderIcon extends Component {
    async componentDidMount(){
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        this.setState({token});
    }
    state={
        token:null
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {
                    this.state.token ===null
                        ?
                        (
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => (NavigationService.navigate("LogStack"))}>
                                <Icon name="ios-power" size={30} style={{color: "white",marginRight:wp("5%")}}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        )
                        :
                        (
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => (NavigationService.navigate("Profile"))}>
                                <Icon name="ios-home" size={30} style={{color: "white",marginRight:wp("5%")}}/>
                            </TouchableOpacity>)
                }
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

The system works exactly as I want. If there is a token, I say icon1 or icon2 show. The problem is I do this in componentDidMount, the icon does not change without refreshing the page. How do I render it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is called, as the name suggests, just once, when the component is mounted. Use `componentDidUpdate` to decide how your component behaves based on what piece of `props` or `state` has changed.

Read the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) for more information regarding lifecycle methods.

Comment: Although he did not take it directly to the solution, he explained the reason for not being indirectly. Thank you very much.